# DateJS missing functions

Tags: javascript

I stumbled on DateJS, Javascript opensource library for date functions. Looks pretty cool.

What is puzzling me is, in the documentation they talk of some functions but those functions are unavailable in the main datejs file, eg.

Example of missing/hidding functions include

```
Date.today().first().monday()
```

I get the error, object Date  has no method first() error

Any idea how this library works?

Gath

Comment: Maybe they mean `(new Date()).today().first().monday()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i got the correct version found [here](http://datejs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/build/date.js). I wish DateJS web site can point the main download to this link.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me using your example. Have you made sure that the date.js include has loaded before using it; try putting your call in your `onload` function rather than being called immediately.

Comment: Other functions are working, like moveToFirstDayOfMonth() and others... but the first(), last() are missing within my dateJS file. Or i my using an old version ??